# use javascript map to extends array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
[{
  "day": "Sat",
  "raw_date": "21/9/2017",
  "value": 123
},{
    "day": "Sun",
    "raw_date": "22/9/2017",
    "value": 4
}]
```

How do I use map to add 3 more days to above array? because I have day property I can't do push, I have to get the last item and proceed from there, I've tried to do this

```
const result = arr.map((obj, i) => {
    if(i === arr.length - 1) { // should add 2 more days here
        return {
            day: moment(obj.day).add(1, 'd').format('DD MMM'),
            raw_date: moment(obj.raw_date).add(1, 'ddd').format('d'),
            value: 0
        }
    }

    return obj
})
```

But how to add 2 more day? using another map? I know I can do that but looking for more elegant approach.

Comment: "I can't do push" — Why not? It's designed to add things to arrays.

Comment: " I have to get the last item and proceed from there" — so use `arr[arr.length - 1]`

Comment: I think the more elegant way is to use `push`. (Unless, of course, that's some kind of school problem to test your understanding of map.)

Comment: Hi @CeciliaChan, why you want to use map here? It is not helpful here. simply push more values based on the last object values

Comment: @Quentin How to calculate the date if I use push?

Comment: Mapping means it is a 1 to 1 transformation, unless you want to do a flap map which is not supported natively in JS

Comment: @RohitAgrawal push 3 dates?

Comment: @CeciliaChan, I have updated my answer to vary number of dates to be pushed

Comment: @dork push will not able to push 3 different value of property base on last item inserted.

Comment: @CeciliaChan, you can just get the previous item and then push an item based on the previous item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use map here.

```
 var numberOfDates = 2;//change here if you want to vary it
 for(var i=0; i < numberOfDates; i++){
        var lastObj = arr[arr.length -1];
        arr.push({
            day: moment().isoWeekday(lastObj.day).add(1,'day').format('ddd'),
            raw_date: moment(lastObj.raw_date, 'DD/M/YYYY').add(1,'day').format('DD/M/YYYY'),
            value: 0
        });
 }
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dp7rzmw5/4360/

Comment: lastObj is not defined

Comment: @CeciliaChan forgot to declare variable lastObj. Updated my answer. Can you please check now

Comment: this won't work, tried it, I got same raw_date and day after the push, u might want to try ur solution in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi @CeciliaChan, please check this out. It is working in jsfiddle

Comment: link? u missed the link.

Comment: what's the 3rd param in moment for?

Comment: The 3rd parameter(true) is needed for date objects creation and it can be dropped for your example. Have you tried the solution now with my updated answer?  It is working and let me know if you are facing any problem in implementing this

Comment: @CeciliaChan, Please let me know if it is working or not and accepting the answer it it does.

Answer (score 0):

`array.map` function is for transform the array length of values. And just think(tricky way) how you are going to use ***array functions*** as per your requirement. 
or
Just go with `for()`.

Refer here https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/array-map-filter-and-reduce-js